# Mootools set element text without clobbering child nodes

Tags: mootools

With Mootools, what's the cleanest way of setting an element's text without overwriting any child nodes?

I want to go from this

```
<div id="foo">
  foo
  <div id="bar">
    bar
  </div>
</div>
```

... to this

```
<div id="foo">
  new improved foo
  <div id="bar">
    bar
  </div>
</div>
```

I thought this would do it:

```
$('foo').set('text', 'new improved foo')
```

but that replaces the whole element contents, resulting in

```
<div id="foo">
  new improved foo
</div>
```

<strike>(btw, this is identical to `set('html', ...)` AFAICS. Is this a Mootools bug?)</strike>

Comment: no, it is not. try `el.set('html', '<strong>hi</strong>');` vs `el.set('text', '<strong>hi</strong>');` and you will see the difference.

Comment: @DimitarChristoff ah true, scratch that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If text content is always the first thing inside your tags, you can try to get all children elements, **edit text and then re-inject children later**.

```
var myChildren = $('foo').getChildren().dispose();
$('foo').set('text', 'new improved foo');
$('foo').adopt(myChildren);
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/x2Vke/

---

Anyway, if you can edit your HTML code, I suggest you to **wrap your text contents in some inline tag** like `<span>` and reference to it in order to replace text:

```
<div id="foo">
  <span class="text-content">foo</span>
  <div id="bar">
    bar
  </div>
</div>
```

Then you can simply do:

```
$('foo').getFirst('.text-content').set('text', 'new improved foo');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hMNXN/

Comment: thanks - rearranging the html so the text is in a leaf node is the cleanest way